# How to update the OpenShift Online 3 platform to the latest version of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-enterprise

At the age of OpenShift Online 2 there was an ability to [update Node.js](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/243-node-js-latest) to the latest version. As far as I can see, this approach doesn't work anymore for the new OpenShift Online 3 version. Currently, OpenShift offers only outdated or LTS versions of Node.js, e.g. v.4 or v.6.

How can I update the OpenShift Online 3 platform to the latest/current version of Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this alternate S2I builder for Node.js.

- https://github.com/ryanj/origin-s2i-nodejs

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is it possible to install it on the free account of OpenShift? As far as I know, they limits you quite significantly in this mode.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that image wouldn't work.

Comment: Perhaps, the artificial limit to amount of available processes in the free account…

Comment: The limit is on the amount of memory, which is really driven by how much memory is allocated to a pod and so how many pods you have. The default allocation per pod is 512MB and so you can have 2 pods. If you can for some pods adjust it down to 256MB, then you could fit more pods. Use of this specific image is not going to change that.

Answer (score 2):

Updated S2I images are available here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-nodejs/

Comment: To install the above images in your namespace: `oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bucharest-gold/origin-s2i-nodejs/master/image-streams.json`

Comment: the name of the project changed from bucharest-gold to nodeshift, so the newest images will be at https://hub.docker.com/r/nodeshift/centos7-s2i-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

New versions are available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/nodeshift/centos7-s2i-nodejs/)

Our team changed the name from bucharest-gold to nodeshift.
So you can find more updated versions in that new address.

Node.js versions:

```
10.15.1 -- 13 days ago
11.9.0  -- 13 days ago
11.8.0  -- 16 days ago
```

Comment: I wish OpenShift would be as easy-to-use and bugs-free as Heroku. No need to install any CLI, just bind Heroku with GitHub via web-interface, and specify a desired version of Node.js in `package.json` of your app. The rest will be performed automatically by Heroku, just plug & play, such amazing DevOps experience!